# Has anybody tried to change and benchmark different javascript query servers with CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, benchmarking

CouchDB ships with a default JS query server, couchJS, which is in charge of interpreting JS views (and filters, and shows) and seems to be a version of Mozilla SpiderMonkey. The one shipping with CouchDB 1.0.1 seems to be SpiderMonkey 1.8.5, if you look at the strings within the binary. However, there are other (many, in fact) JS engines out there, from V8 to JägerMonkey, which might offer (or maybe not) better performance, at least with complicated views or filters. 
Has anybody tried that? Would it be worth the while? (Maybe the first question would be would they work? and even have you tried it yourself?, but, hey, I can do it if nobody has, don't want to waste my time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB links against SpiderMonkey, so CouchDB 1.0.1 might run with any of a large variety of SpiderMonkey releases. (Similarly, your browser might run one of many releases of the Java or Flash plugin.)

I maintain [Build-CouchDB](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb) and that does build a pretty recent SpiderMonkey, for presumed tracing JIT improvements; however I have never seen a benchmark.

The general consensus is that the JavaScript VM execution speed is not the bottleneck for CouchDB and so making it faster would not make CouchDB appreciably faster.